# k-NN interesting for classification and regression, but poor for probability density estimation

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour, density-estimation

Why are k-NN interesting for classification and regression, but poorly suited for probability density estimation? It seems there is some issues near the data causing problem to well estimate a probability density function.

**EDIT**

A hint has been given to me, but I can't see how it helps.

[image]

**Pattern recognition and machine learning** by *Bishop, Christopher M* page 125.

Am I wrong to say the density estimation $p(x)$
does not work very well with k-NN approach
because the resulting density estimate

1. Is not even a density
2. Has a lot of discontinuities (looks very spiky,
   not differentiable)
3. Even for large regions with no observed
   samples the estimated density is far from zero
   (tails are too heavy)

Comment: Said whom? Could you provide context for this quote?

Comment: Variations of k-NN are very popular in weather forecasting, check for example the Analog Ensemble technique